# JPA and hibernate for Flex

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, blazeds, database

I'm using JPA but I'm not sure how to use it for
relation between two classes. I need to connect them
@OneToMany. I have done this before but forgot.
Is there any good tutorial for this or an example that
is easy to understand.

By the way this is a Flex application where I'm using
BlazeDS for connection between Java and Flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Introduction to the Java Persistence API](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html) in The Java EE 5 Tutorial and more precisely the section on [Multiplicity in Entity Relationships](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqh).

Comment: I have already seen this. But what I need is an example or tutorial for how to write the code correctly.
For the moment I'm not sure about how to map @OneToMany ???  With what class???

Comment: @dejaninic There are two examples in the tutorial (http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbrt.html and http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbsw.html). Without details on your object model, it's impossible to provide more guidance (how could readers tell you how to map your classes if you don't say anything about them?).